# Возвращение на ту же страницу. Интернационализация приложение

Tags: html, jsp, jstl, i18n

Доброго день! Возникла такая проблема, как переход на ту же страницу с которой была вызвана другая, т.е. например, я отправляю форму на обработку другой jsp-странице, а потом страница возвращает ответ на страницу с которой была вызвана.
Суть в том, что другая страница не знает наперед с какой странице будет вызвана, вопрос в том: как передать путь вызывающей страницы в другую?
Интернационализация здесь при том, что это я делаю для изменения языка в приложении.
    Страница, с которой вызываю другую страницу для изменения языка:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %>
<tr>
<td class="footer">
    <form action="changeLocale.jsp" method="post">
        <fmt:message key="language"/>:
        <select name="locale" onchange="submit()">
            <c:forEach items="${applicationScope.locales}" var="locale">
                <c:set var="selected" value="${locale.key == currentLocale ?     'selected' : '' }"/>
                <option value="${locale.key}" ${selected}>${locale.value}    </option>
            </c:forEach>
        </select>
    </form>
</td>
</tr>
```

Страница, которая изменяет язык и возвращается на ту же страницу(наперед она не знает с какой страницы будет вызвана):

```
changeLocale.jsp

<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %>

<fmt:setLocale value="${param.locale}" scope="session"/>

<fmt:setBundle basename="resources"/>

<c:set var="currentLocale" value="${param.locale}" scope="session"/>

<jsp:forward page="путь к jsp-странице, с которой вызвали эту"/>
```

Буду рад любому ответу!

Answer (score 1):

В сервлете:

```
String path = request.getRequestURI();
String query = request.getQueryString();
query = query == null ? "" : "?" + query;
request.setAttribute("currentUrl", path + query);
```

затем в jsp:

```
${requestScope.currentUrl}
```

Comment: Хоть ответ может и решит пролему, но у вас явно с логикой в приложении беда. Такие костыли не делают. Думаю есть намного проще техника.